# How to run a .sh (shell script) file in GDB?

Tags: shell, gdb

I have a script file named `simple`. I can run it using `./simple` and everything works fine as it should.

I need to run this file in GDB to back trace how one particular parameter is changed and by what functions is it called. when I try

```
(gdb) file simple
```

> "/home/examples/simple": not in executable format: File format not recognized

```
(gdb) r simple
```

> Starting program:  simple

> No executable file specified.

> Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.`

How can I overcome this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 4):

GDB is debugger for compiled languages (like C/C++) not for shell scripts. If you need debug Bash script you can use [`-x` flag](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html).

Comment: Thank you.. i know thar GDB is for languages like c/c++.but my question was how can i change my .sh file to run it in GDB. anyhow, I just had to make a small change in my script file.. it is working fine now.. thank you once again..